# Document id of Mongo document using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Below is code to retrieve all documents in collection.

```
db.collection('movies', function(err, collectionref) {          
    // find all documents in a collection that have foo: "bar"
    var cursor = collectionref.find({});
    cursor.toArray(function(err, docs) {
        // gets executed once all items are retrieved
        res.render('movie', {'movies': docs});
    });
});
```

I want the id of all documents in collection using node js.

Comment: Are you talking about _id?? If yes , then its there in your docs

Comment: Yes i want _id..how to iterate on docs to get all ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate on cursor object to get _id like this:

```
var cursor = db.inventory.find( {} );
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
  console.log(tojson(cursor.next())._id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, since it's just JavaScript, you're provided with normal collection iterators:

```
// find all documents that are "movies"
db.movies.find({})
.map(function(doc) {
  // iterate and return only the _id field for each document
  return doc._id;
});
```

The more formal MongoDB-ish name for this is [`cursor.map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/cursor.map/), which:

> Applies function to each document visited by the cursor and collects the return values from successive application into an array.

The example in the docs in the link I provided is also pretty clear:

```
db.users.find().map( function(u) { return u.name; } );
```

This functionality mimics the native [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in many ways (I would suggest reading those docs as well if you are not familiar with that method).